# Symfony 4 can not execute binary file after installing it

Tags: php, bash, symfony

I use the command from the Symfony download page: `curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash` then move the binary file to my  local bin folder `sudo mv /home/guervyl/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony`. But when I execute the file `symfony new --full my_project` I get the error `bash: / usr / local / bin / symfony: can not execute binary file: format error for exec ()` this is a translation. The original error is `bash: /usr/local/bin/symfony : impossible d'exécuter le fichier binaire : Erreur de format pour exec()`.

Is symfony CLI for X64? My pc is a linux Debian system I386.

Note: `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project` works fine.

Comment: The Symfony binary has gone away for Symfony 4.  I can't explain your particular error though it seems like you need to do a "chmod +x symfony" to make it executable.  But again, it will not create Symfony 4 projects.

Comment: It has already execution permission. So I just have to remove it and keep using composer then.